# What are the available parser(s) for scala programming language?

Tags: scala, parsing

Are there any user friendly parser(s) available for code written in scala programming language ?

I am aware about [scaliriform](https://github.com/mdr/scalariform), but it is very basic and only extracts tokens with offsets.

Comment: Do you mean you want to parse the Scala language, or do you want a library or module for Scala that can help you with parsing of other programming languages?

Comment: I want to parse code written in scala language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [fastparse library](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse) by Li Haoyi contains a [grammar for the scala language](https://github.com/lihaoyi/fastparse/tree/master/scalaparse) that has been tested with a large number of projects from github. I think this is the most lightweight and approachable way to parse scala.

Here is [some documentation](http://lihaoyi.github.io/fastparse/#UsingScalaParse) to get you started.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2. Do you have a preference, @ RüdigerKlaehn?

Comment: I like fastparse because it does not use macros and seems to be conceptually similar to scala-parser-combinators. Also, it seems to be pretty fast. But maybe I have just not gotten into parboiled2 yet.

Comment: I am not accepting it as an answer, because this sort of setup arguably lacks the user friendly aspect.

Comment: @scrapcodes what do you want to do with it? Have you asked for help on the fastparse gitter? Doing anything non-trivial with a large and complex grammar like scala is not going to be user friendly (as in beginner-friendly).